# Row instead of columns

Tags: python, csv

I want the following output in the csv file to be in rows, not columns. I do not get how to manage that.

```
with open(s, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([u['username'] for u in followers])
```

Comment: post a testable input sample and expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(s, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for u in followers:
        writer.writerow([u['username']])
```

Comment: No way! That easy! Thanks so much! Didn't see that!

Comment: @daniel_e if this answers your question, please accept it (and upvote).